# How select multiple dropdown in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example

```
<select name="test" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Select One value from dropdown is

```
$("select[name=test]").val("1");
```

But How to select multiple options using jquery?

[image]

Please help to solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049710/how-to-select-options-in-multiple-select-list-with-jquery

Comment: Look at this answer, it works perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710518/12837415

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```js
$("select[name=test]").val([1,2,3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1 This is first</option>
  <option value="2">2 This is second</option>
  <option value="3">3 This is third</option>
  <option value="4">4 This is fourth</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try it:

```
$('select option[value=' + val + ']').attr('selected', true);
```