# How to set selected value in multiple select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sPKAY/78/)

Multi Select List:

```
<select id="fruits" name="fruits" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Orange</option>
 </select>
```

Script Code:

```
var groups=["Apple","Orange"]; //Only Apple and orange values should be selected
$('#fruits').val(groups);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `value`s correct. As of now you are passing the text not values.

```
var groups=[1,3];
```

```js
var groups=[1,3];
$('#fruits').val(groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruits" name="fruits" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Orange</option>
 </select>
```

However still you want to use texts i.e. `["Apple","Orange"];`, `.filter()` method can be used along with `.prop()`

```js
var groups = ["Apple", "Orange"];
$('#fruits option').filter(function() {
  return groups.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1; //Options text exists in array
}).prop('selected', true); //Set selected
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fruits" name="fruits" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049710/how-to-select-options-in-multiple-select-list-with-jquery for another method.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.

```js
    var groups = ["Apple", "Orange"];

    $('#fruits').val(groups);

    $('select[name*="fruits"]').find('option').each(function() {
      var str = $(this).text()
      if (!contains(groups, str)) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });

    function contains(a, obj) {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="fruits" name="fruits" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
</select>
```